# Compare two csv files containing similar columns, eliminate duplicate and output unique content in one file

Tags: windows, powershell, ubuntu, compare

I have two csv files (similar format)

file1.csv

```
 post_status    post_type   post_content    post_title
 publish        post        paragraph one   title one
 publish        post        paragraph two   title two
 publish        post        paragraph three title three
 publish        post        paragraph four  title four
```

file2.csv

```
 post_status    post_type   post_content    post_title
 publish        post        paragraph one   title one
 publish        post        paragraph two   title two
 publish        post        paragraph three title three
 publish        post        paragraph four  title four
 publish        post        paragraph five  title five
 publish        post        paragraph six   title six
```

Desired-output.csv

```
 post_status    post_type   post_content    post_title
 publish        post        paragraph five  title five
 publish        post        paragraph six   title six
```

The solutions I have gotten so far are using Power Shell and this:

```
cat first.csv second.csv | sort -u >result.csv
```

This produces results that don't maintain consistency of the original file.

I am using Ubuntu and Windows. Looking for a simple elegant solution. Any and all help will be appreciated.

Comment: @whatever Thanks. And which platform would I try this? Windows cmd or Ubuntu's terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$Content = Get-Content first.csv,second.csv
$Content | Select-Object -Unique | Out-File result.csv
```

This solution is for Windows Powershell

Actually, you can do all in one line:

```
Get-Content first.csv,second.csv | Select-Object -Unique | Out-File result.csv
```

The only difference between your version and mine (besides from using the linux aliases for the powershell cmds) is that you are using Sort-Object which will change the order of the entries.:)